# SOLVED No HDMI video after boot sequence

Tags: pi-4, hdmi

Raspberry Pi 4B connected via micro-HDMI to HDMI cable to a 1920x1080 computer monitor. The boot sequence starts with text being printed to the screen (splash screen off) and when it should switch to graphics mode, it goes blank. The monitor says there is no signal and then goes into standby mode. Pi OS is running and I can ssh in.

What I've tried:

- Uncomment `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`
- Uncomment and set `hdmi_group=2` and `hdmi_mode=82`
- Same with `hdmi_drive=2` and `config_hdmi_boost=4`

If I reboot over ssh I can see the boot sequence again but no graphics. What else can I try? Is it possible this is because of a faulty cable? I don't have any other micro HDMI to HDMI to try, and this one can transfer low res (640x480 text mode).

Comment: Try setting hdmi_safe=1 https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#hdmi_safe

Comment: have you verified that the display manager is running when you ssh to your pi? if it isn't running, then maybe try checking it's error messages/status?

Answer (score 10):

After trying many configs and workarounds I found this thread https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1647.

I ssh into Pi and edited `/boot/config.txt` to comment out this line, uncommented by default on the PiOS image. After reboot the graphic environment was finally available.

```
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Comment: This helped me too.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me too, thanks!


Acer 24" (1920x1080, supports up to 144hz)
Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB)

Like what MatsK said below, I had display signal for everything starting up, and when it said "Welcome to Raspberry Pi", then the monitor would say "No Signal"; this is what fixed that problem.

Comment: This is about 2 years later and I'm having the same issue. I checked and the line specified here was already uncommented in /boot/config.text, so I commented it out and there was no change. I finally got it to work by commenting out "#disable_fw_kms_setup=1" and rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comment from `#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`, as suggested by kaldimar solved this for me after hours of fighting other (non)issues.

**NOTE:** This is for the display signal being lost after the 4 pixel and "Welcome to Raspberry pi" screen has already come up.

Answer (score 2):

This might be the most stupid answer, but I wasted 3 days with troubleshooting just to find the following solution: If your Raspberry Pi is in a case, make sure that it's screwed in correctly and that the HDMI Pin reaches deep enough into the port. To check, unscrew it from the case and try booting it

Answer (score 0):

In the config.txt file look for the line with dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d and change it to dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d (add an f in front of kms on that line).

Switches to an older driver, not my fix but from raspberry forums